# How to deny consent to cookies - say no to presented check-boxes using browser console

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, console

I often get these cookie consent pop-up windows and go through them manually to un-check some of the already checked ones.

Via the Browser Console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked[role="button"]').forEach(function(element){element.click()});
```

The above would select all the checked boxes and fire a click event on them to turn them off :)

Would there be a better approach?

Comment: Every consent screen I run into is different, I don't think you can write a generic code for them. I don't think I've ever seen one with checkboxes, it's usually just an "I agree" button.

Comment: I have seen ones with checkboxes that are for selecting specific things to allow/block. However, since all of the popups are different I don't think you are doing to create a universal code that takes all variations into consideration. They are annoying but are going to become more and more common even in the US.

Comment: @Barmar Here is one example of many website using checkboxes (a lot of them actually; check the vendors section): https://growserenity.com/ For these, I had to modify the line in my question, to remove the [role="button"] and it works just fine, in 2 seconds all the check boxes are unchecked :) If one would use Brave Browser, it will automatically take the cookie consent dialog out.

Comment: I don't get any cookie consent request at that site, and I don't see a vendors section. There's a "Cookie Policy" link in the footer, it says to disable cookies for the site if you don't want them to use them.

Comment: @Barmar here you have two screenshots: https://pasteboard.co/QDnby4jJST3r.png  and  https://pasteboard.co/vxGTKIwyNP4Y.png   for https://growserenity.com/  from my end.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it because I'm not in Europe, so CDPR doesn't apply to me? Also, I never drill into "Manage settings" options, I always choose "Allow cookies".